# LIN bus sniffing with Arduino

Tags: arduino, automotive, lin

I'm trying to do a simple LIN bus sniffing in my car with an Arduino.
This should be possible with a simple voltage divider if I'm not wrong.

Would this schematic work?

```
0-12V in
       |
     [10k]
       |
       +-->0 to 4.86V out to Arduino
       |
     [6k8]
       |
      VEHICLE GND
```

Comment: Why don't you use a LIN transceiver like [this one](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV7428-D.PDF) ?

Comment: I don't need to send any information, only listen for a given command.

Comment: Then you should use a buffer, anyways. It's not guaranteed to have 12VDC for the logic-hi on LIN, so you may not get ~5VDC on logic-hi. I would use a comparator plus a buffer.

Comment: This question has corresponding answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493172/connect-to-lin-bus-with-logic-level-shifter-as-transceiver

Comment: Did you succeed with linbus sniffing on your car

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to LIN bus with logic level shifter as transceiver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493172/connect-to-lin-bus-with-logic-level-shifter-as-transceiver)

Comment: @obd2centerpro No, i bought a LINbus sniffer module, but sold the car before i could test it :(